# I can't remove dates that appear in my amount column of a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have tried with extracting patterns and with different pandas.DataFrame methods and have not achieved it.

```
new_data = data["amount"].replace(to_replace='str', value=None)
new_data.sort_values()

7212    1/01/1018
1883    1/02/1027
7494    1/02/1103
3030    1/03/1268
5168    1/04/1053
          ...    
1282       987.12
7122       988.00
23         989.20
6503       996.95
6399       997.06
Name: amount, Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

I have tried in different ways but I am still unable to remove only the dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to_numeric and change all non numeric to NA then drop them

`pd.to_numeric(df['amount'], errors='coerce').dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
data =[('1','10/10/2018'), ('2','34345.00'),('3','11/10/2018')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data , columns=['keycol', 'amount'])

df1.loc[df1.amount.str.contains('/'),"amount"]=None
```